# GitLab API to get all commits of a specific branch

Tags: api, branch, gitlab

By default, the API `GET /projects/:id/repository/commits` gets commits of master branch, but I want to get other branch's commits.

Comment: It says it in the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits

Comment: Look at the `ref_name` attribute in Oliver's link

Comment: Thank you!  I have resolved.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html) you can add parameter "ref_name" and specify the branch from which you want to get the commits:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/commits?ref_name=my_branch_name
```

Comment: If you want to get all commits (not just 20, which is default), set `per_page` attribute value to, for example, `9999`

Comment: max for per_page is 100 and default is 20. If you use 9999 as per above comment, it will be ignored and max 100 will be considered.

Answer (score 3):

I will complement the answer by K. Gol:
Need to add params: `per_page` and `page`.
The value more than 100 has been ignored for the param `per_page`.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-references-a-commit-is-pushed-to

Answer (score 0):

You could get all commits from specific branch using my recursive node js code:

```
class GitlabAPI {
  host = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4";
  project = null;
  constructor(host, project) {
    this.host = host;
    this.project = project;
  }

  async loadCommits(branch, commits = [], page = 1) {
    const url = `${this.host}/projects/${this.project}/repository/commits`;

    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      params: { all: "true", per_page: 100, page, ref_name: branch },
    });

    console.log(`Parse ${page} page, results: ${response.data.length} commits`);

    if (response.data.length > 0) {
      return await this.loadCommits(branch, commits.concat(response.data), page + 1);
    } else {
      return commits;
    }
  }

  async commits(branch) {
    try {
      const commits = await this.loadCommits(branch);
      return commits;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

And, voila:

```
const host = process.env.GITLAB_HOST;
const project_id = 325;
const branch = "master";
const GL = new GitlabAPI(host, project_id);

const commits = await GL.commits(branch);
```

Happy coding!