# GitLab API:How to get branches order by commit_time

Tags: api, gitlab

I want to list application's all branches in front side and want the list can be ordered by branch last commit time.

But currently there are two questions :

1. gitLab api return 20 branches by default, I searched that add per_pages can return more branches.
2. gitLab api is ordered by name.

Is anyone know if there are some unpublic parameters to resolve my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you will have a better chance of getting an answer if there is only one question per post. In any case,

> Is anyone know if there are some unpublic parameters to resolve my problem?

There are no, as far as I know, private parameters in the GitLab API. They should all be listed in the [API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/).

> gitLab api return 20 branches by default, I searched that add per_pages can return more branches.

Indeed, you can change the `per_page` parameter to return up to a maximum of 100 items per page, and/or [use pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination) in your client.

> gitLab api is ordered by name.

Looking at the [branches API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html) it would seem that that is the only sorting available.

In that case, one option is to do the sorting on your client: you can use the branches API to list the branches, and the [commits API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html) to fetch [the commits of each branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733179/gitlab-api-to-get-all-commits-of-a-specific-branch) and then determine the last commit to do the sorting.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

gitlab Restful api get Branches:

`/api/v4/projects/{git_id}/repository/branches`

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html

support params: `page` `per_page` `sort` `search`

`/api/v4/projects/{git_id}/repository/branches?page=1&per_page=100&sort=updated_desc`

can resolve "How to get branches order by commit_time"

Comment: Thanks for sharing this and it worked well. I have a hard time finding documentation regarding the sort flag. The only place I could find anything remotely related to updated_desc was here: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/06/04/gitlab-moving-to-14-breaking-changes/